System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named 'Inventory_G2' in DLL 'UHFReader288.dll'.'
I keep getting this error when running my project code in C#. I am using SEUIC RFID UF3-B using TCP protocol. When running my code, I always get an error like this:
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named 'Inventory_G2' in DLL 'UHFReader288.dll'.'
What do you think is the reason for this? I have asked ChatGPT about this, and tried to solve it by updating the .NET Framework version to 3.5, adding a reference to the project, and adding the UHFReader288.dll file to the .../x86/Release/ directory, but the error is still there.
Can you help me?
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace UHFReaderModule
{
    public class TagReader
    {
        private byte comAddr;
        private byte qValue;
        private byte session;
        private byte maskMem;
        private byte[] maskAdr;
        private byte maskLen;
        private byte[] maskData;
        private byte maskFlag;
        private byte adrTID;
        private byte lenTID;
        private byte tidFlag;
        private byte target;
        private byte inAnt;
        private byte scanTime;
        private byte fastFlag;

        public TagReader(byte comAddr)
        {
            this.comAddr = comAddr;
            this.qValue = 0; // Atur QValue sesuai kebutuhan
            this.session = 0x00; // Gunakan S0 sebagai nilai sesi
            this.maskMem = 0x01; // Gunakan EPC memory
            this.maskAdr = new byte[2] { 0x00, 0x00 }; // Alamat masker
            this.maskLen = 0; // Tidak ada masker
            this.maskData = new byte[0]; // Tidak ada data masker
            this.maskFlag = 0; // Nonaktifkan masker
            this.adrTID = 0; // Alamat TID
            this.lenTID = 0; // Panjang TID
            this.tidFlag = 0; // Inventarisasi EPC
            this.target = 0x00; // Target A
            this.inAnt = 0x80; // Antena 1
            this.scanTime = 0; // Tidak ada batas waktu
            this.fastFlag = 0; // Nonaktifkan fast inventory
        }

        public bool ReadTag(out int cardNum) // `out` parameter untuk cardNum
        {
            byte[] pEPCList = new byte[1024]; // Buffer untuk menyimpan data EPC
            byte ant = 0;
            int totalLength = 0;

            // Inisialisasi cardNum sebelum pemanggilan fungsi
            cardNum = 0;

            // Panggil metode Inventory_G2
            int result = Inventory_G2(ref comAddr, qValue, session, maskMem, maskAdr, maskLen, maskData, maskFlag,
                adrTID, lenTID, tidFlag, target, inAnt, scanTime, fastFlag, pEPCList, ref ant, ref totalLength, ref cardNum);

            if (result == 0) // Sukses
            {
                return cardNum > 0; // Kembalikan true jika ada tag yang terbaca
            }
            else
            {
                cardNum = 0; // Tidak ada tag yang terbaca
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool ReadTagData(byte[] epc, out int errorCode)
        {
            errorCode = 0; // Inisialisasi errorCode
                           // Implementasi membaca data tag akan dilakukan di sini.

            // Misalkan Anda memiliki metode untuk membaca data EPC dari tag.
            // Contoh: Kita hanya mengisi dengan dummy data.
            if (epc.Length < 8) // Pastikan panjang epc cukup
            {
                errorCode = -1; // Mengatur errorCode jika panjang tidak sesuai
                return false; // Gagal
            }

            // Isi data dengan contoh dummy
            Array.Copy(new byte[] { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x9A, 0xBC, 0xDE, 0xF0 }, epc, 8); // Dummy data
            return true; // Kembalikan true sebagai tanda pembacaan sukses
        }

        [DllImport("UHFReader288.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern int Inventory_G2(ref byte ComAddr, byte QValue, byte Session, byte MaskMem, byte[] MaskAdr,
            byte MaskLen, byte[] MaskData, byte MaskFlag, byte AdrTID, byte LenTID, byte TIDFlag, byte Target,
            byte InAnt, byte Scantime, byte FastFlag, byte[] pEPCList, ref byte Ant, ref int Totallen, ref int CardNum);
    }
}

I also checked the functions in UHDReader288.dll using JetBrains dotPeek, and the function is there. Where do you think I am wrong?

Check the signature of the function - the one that comes up in public GitHub looks like it's changed and the last few parameters have been removed.
